# Unexpected Sinatra 404 GET error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sinatra, thin

Running a 'classic' Sinatra app on Thin (1.6.3).

The page seems to load fine, but then I noticed:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2015:15:39:08 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2869 0.0028
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2015:15:39:08 -0600] "GET /css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0009
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2015:15:39:08 -0600] "GET /... HTTP/1.1" 404 440 0.0011
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2015:15:39:08 -0600] "GET /js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0007
```

This line (`"GET /... HTTP/1.1" 404`) is present for all routes, not just `/`.

Why am I getting this message?  What does the ellipsis `...` represent in this context?

Both the local (CSS, JS) and remote resources (ajax.googleapis.com) seem to load correctly.

The route:

```
get '/' do
  erb :'/home'
end
```

The view:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</div>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit.</p></blockquote>
```

The layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: At a glance I would recommend trying it without the '/' in front of '/home'
get '/' do
  erb :home
end

Comment: @jdussault: tried; same result

Comment: Ah sorry, I should have looked more closely.  I was thinking it couldn't find your view but if your page is loading that is definitely not the case.  :/

Comment: If you bring up the network inspector in your browser does it show the same?

Comment: @froderik: yes, the same.

Comment: if you remove the scripts? only thing that could make a call is one of the scripts. (Also tried different browsers etc?)